# HP Pavilion with Ubuntu 16.04.5 WiFi not working

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet

I have a brand new HP Pavilion x360 convertible with a fresh install of ***Ubuntu 16.04.5***.

The WiFi is not working; none of the WiFi networks are even showing up. Ethernet is also not working; if I plug in an Ethernet cable is shows up as 'wired network 1' but when I try to connect to it it fails.

This is part of the output from running `lspci`:
`Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822`

I think the issue is that the network controller is too recent and doesn't have Ubuntu support yet. I'm not sure how to fix this as without internet connection I can't download new WiFi drivers.

None of the solutions that I found online worked for me. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SO MUCH pomsky! I don't know why I didn't find that while googling the issue. Turning secure boot off fixed everything, I am so relieved.

Edit: for anyone with a similar issue, I rebooted my computer and pressed the esc key twice when it first turned back on to get to the BIOS menu. Then I turned secure boot off, saved and exited, restarted my computer, and the WiFi worked right away.